# Combinations in ROOT

Tags: c++, combinations, root-framework

What does the Combinations function do in ROOT/C++?
I only found this documentation
 https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/namespaceROOT_1_1VecOps.html#a6d1d00c2ccb769cc48c6813dbeb132db
But I am still not sure what it does exactly.
Can someone provide an example showing how the answers in the documentation examples are computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what Combinations is doing:

Suppose you have a vector v{1., 2., 3., 4.,} 
1, 2, 3, and 4 are the elements of the vector v
and 0, 1, 2, 3 are the indices of those elements. 
If we write

```
Combinations (v, 2)
```

we get

```
{{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2} , { 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3}}.
```

That comes from looking at the different combinations of the vector elements. 
Which are:

1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 3
2, 4
3, 4

Which has the corresponding indices

0 1
0 2
0 3
1 2
1 3
2 3

Then, the left-side column makes the first vector in the answer and the right side column makes the second vector shown in the answer.